# Short-form for validates_exclusion_of

Tags: validation, ruby-on-rails-3, model

If

```
validates_presence_of :login,
                      :message => 'How do you expect to login?'
```

has a short-form variant

`validates :login, :presence => { :message => 'How do you expect to login?' }`,

what is the short-form version of

```
validates_exclusion_of :login, :in => ['admin'],
                       :message => "\"{{value}}\" is reserved."
```

so I can also have a custom message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
validates :login, :exclusion => { :in => ['admin'], :message => "%{value} is reserved" }
```